# StockTwits - Rate Limit Exceeded from AWS Instances

Tags: stocktwits

I am trying to use the stocktwits api from an Amazon AWS instance, but it always replies

```
 "{"response":{"status":429},"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded. Client may not make more than 200 requests an hour."}]}"
```

I tried manually entering into Chrome the following api call from two different [AWS instances](https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AACB.json) , both returned the same error.  From Chrome on my home laptop it worked fine and returned the expected json.

Is all AWS blacklisted (it can't be by IP address as mine are unique)?  Otherwise what is the reason that it would say that the rate limit is exceeded on the first time I try to access the API via Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result when I try your request. I think that either that the StockTwits API is having a transient error or that is the default response for an unauthenticated user. Are you authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like StockTwits have recent updated the access levels for the APIs.  Check to see if the API documentation has changed.

I just noticed for the streams/symbol api they have added:

> This API end-point is only available through Partner-Level Access